# Error MysqliDb::$_paramTypeList

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-mysqlidb

I use this https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

this is my my class

```
require_once ('class/MysqliDb.php');

class Foo {

    private  $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = MySqliDb::getInstance();
    }
}

 public function register($password, $email) {

        $password = @sha1($password);

        $query = $this->db
            ->where('email', $email)
            ->get('users');

        if (count($query) == 0)
        {

            $insertData = array(
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $password
            );

            if($this->db->insert('users', $insertData)){
                return true;
            }

        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I save in Db (if `count($query) == 0`) but I also receive this error

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: MysqliDb::$_paramTypeList in /.../class/MysqliDb.php on line 356
```

if I do not write this query

```
$query = $this->db
                ->where('email', $email)
                ->get('users');
```

I Haven't error.
Can I Do multi Query in the single function ? And how i have this error `MysqliDb::$_paramTypeList`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the reset() function in MysqliDb.php

```
protected function reset()
{
    $this->_where = array();
    $this->_bindParams = array(''); // Create the empty 0 index
    unset($this->_query);           //<-- unsetting variables which could be resused
    unset($this->_whereTypeList);
    unset($this->_paramTypeList);
}
```

reset() is be run after every execution method and it unsets the _paramTypeList property instead of just re-initializing it.  so if you go to run a 2nd query with the same db object the _paramTypeList property is no longer defined.

you could fix this by editing the reset() function to reinit those variables back to null instead:

```
protected function reset()
{
    $this->_where = array();
    $this->_bindParams = array(''); // Create the empty 0 index
    $this->_query = null;
    $this->_whereTypeList = null;
    $this->_paramTypeList = null;
}
```